# When a letter is typed while coding, the spyder ide freezes for a moment

Tags: python, spyder

I am running Spyder with the following specs:

- version: 4.2.5 None
- Python version: 3.7.10 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.9.6
- PyQt5 version: 5.9.2
- Operating System: Windows 10

I have an issue with typing the letter "i" in the code editor. When I type that letter, Spyder freezes for a moment and a rounding icon appears to the left of the options tab. At first I thought it was an issue with using Turkish keyboard and there was some conflict of letters "i" and "ı". However, I can write any character such as "Ş","ç","I","İ" and "ı". The only problem is with the letter "i". When I copy and paste the letter, the freeze does not happen.

So far I tried:
*Resetting spyder to factory settings
*Updating ipython

None of them worked and any help would be appreciated.